# Using Eclipse EGit with Rikulo

Tags: dart, rikulo

Currently Rikulo SDK does not have eclipse update mechanism for other plugin such as EGit. Is there some way to use EGit with the the SDK? I see no way to include a repo with the SDK unless I used the eclipse version.

Thanks

Comment: Did you saw pub documentation about Git ? [ http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/dependencies.html#git-packages ]

Answer (score 0):

Rikulo UI is a standard Dart package controlled by [PUB](http://pub.dartlang.org/). Please consult Dart documentation for tools Dart supports.

Comment: .. We have not intention... <- Who is 'we' ?

Comment: Hello Tom, thanks for the info. A simple question - What repo do you use when you are developing with the Dart SDK. Please give me some options. Thanks

Comment: You can consider github or gitlab. Both are great.